# Android Data binding : why getVariable() is not updated?

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I have starting to work with data binding for a new project. I have been able to set values in EditText for a classic User form (lastname, firstname, email ...), using binding.setVariable(myVariable)

I want to save edited information by user, so I tried to use binding.getVariable(). But values (lastname, firstname ...) are not updated after user has edited the EditText. So, is it possible to use it like this and I'm doing it wrong, or can we only get updated EditText like this ? :

```
String name = binding.editText_lastname.getText().toString();
```

Here is my method to save data (I'm using Retrofit2 and Realm by the way) :

```
public void saveBtnClick(View view) {

    String name = binding.lastname.getText().toString(); //here I have the new value, after I edited the EditText


    ProfileREST profileREST = LoginREST.retrofit.create(ProfileREST.class);
    profileREST.updateUser(new ProfileBody(binding.getUserviewmodel().getUser()))
            .enqueue(new Callback<User>() { //here I'm getting User object using data binding, values haven't been updated
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

            realm.beginTransaction();
            user.firstname = binding.getUserviewmodel().getUser().firstname;
            user.lastname = binding.getUserviewmodel().getUser().firstname;
            user.phoneNumber = binding.getUserviewmodel().getUser().firstname;
            user.isDarkMode = binding.getUserviewmodel().getUser().isDarkMode;
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

For your information, I'm using two classes for User. One extending RealmObject and one extending BaseObservable (from android.databinding package). I have to wrap the RealmObject as a ViewModel and use the bindable annotation. Because a class which extend RealmObject won't work with data binding. So my onCreate method look like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    binding.getRoot().requestFocus();
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    user = realm.where(User.class).findFirst();
    if(user != null) {
        UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel(user);
        binding.setUserviewmodel(userViewModel);
    }

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is your expression a 2-way data binding expression? e.g. `android:text="@={variable}"`

Comment: Yes it is, in my xml I have android:text="@={userViewModel.firstname}" for example

Comment: It should work. You should see `UserViewModel.setFirstname()` called whenever the user changes the text. If you don't have a setter, then the field should be updated. You won't see any errors if user is null, so be sure to check that. Also, verify that you're checking UserViewModel and not the realm. If your UserViewModel doesn't update the realm when the value changes, you may not be seeing the value change.